# Android CountDown Timer won't stop

Tags: java, android

Ok so here is my problem. I am working on a trivia game that uses a question counter to display 10 questions and once that happens it calls the finalscore class. I have implemented a timer that resets for every question and if time runs up it proceeds to the next question. However if nothing is clicked on the final question it will keep looping back to the finalscore class even after starting a new game.

```
public class game extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

// int[] anArray;
int[] anArray2 = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }; 
int numberOfQuestionsDisplayedCounter = 0; 

int nextOrFinishValue = 0; 

int randomValueZeroToThree = 0; 
int randomValue0to29 = 0; 
boolean alreadyDisplayQuestion = false; 
boolean validQuestionNumber = false;
boolean rightButton1 = false; 
boolean rightButton2 = false; 
boolean rightButton3 = false; 
boolean rightButton4 = false;
String questionFromDatabase; 
String answer1FromDatabase; 
String answer2FromDatabase; 
String answer3FromDatabase; 
String answer4FromDatabase; 
String displayedQuestionFromDatabase = "question "; 
String displayedAnswer1FromDatabase = "answer1a ";
String displayedAnswer2FromDatabase = "answer2a "; 
String displayedAnswer3FromDatabase = "answer3a "; 
String displayedAnswer4FromDatabase = "answer4a "; 

int categoryId = 0; 
int questionId = 0; 
int currentScore = 0;
private CountDownTimer mCountDown;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int randomInt = 1;

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    categoryId = com.triviagame.Trivia_Game.categoryIdInMainMenu;
    // System.out.println("categoryID =" + categoryId);

    setContentView(R.layout.displayquestion);

    // gathers question and answers from database
    gatherInfoBeforePopulating(); // includes generating random number
                                    // between getting info from database 1
                                    // to 30

    // displays question, answers, score
    populateWithQuestionInfo(displayedQuestionFromDatabase,
            displayedAnswer1FromDatabase, displayedAnswer2FromDatabase,
            displayedAnswer3FromDatabase, displayedAnswer4FromDatabase,
            nextOrFinishValue);

    // Sets buttons and listers for the buttons with the 4 possible answers
    View answer1button = findViewById(R.id.answer1button);
    answer1button.setOnClickListener(this);
    View answer2button = findViewById(R.id.answer2button);
    answer2button.setOnClickListener(this);
    View answer3button = findViewById(R.id.answer3button);
    answer3button.setOnClickListener(this);
    View answer4button = findViewById(R.id.answer4button);
    answer4button.setOnClickListener(this);

    final TextView myCounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

    mCountDown = new CountDownTimer(21000, 1000) {

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

            questionCheck();

            resetTimer();

        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            myCounter.setText("Time left: "
                    + String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000));
        }
    }.start();

}

// Displays question, answers, score
public void populateWithQuestionInfo(String question, String answer1,
        String answer2, String answer3, String answer4,
        int nextQuestionOrFinish) {
    // populate the question label
    TextView questionLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
    questionLabel.setText(question);

    // populate answer1
    Button buttonAnswer1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer1button);
    buttonAnswer1.setText(answer1);

    // populate answer2
    Button buttonAnswer2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer2button);
    buttonAnswer2.setText(answer2);

    // populate answer3
    Button buttonAnswer3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer3button);
    buttonAnswer3.setText(answer3);

    // populate answer4
    Button buttonAnswer4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer4button);
    buttonAnswer4.setText(answer4);

    numberOfQuestionsDisplayedCounter++;

}

// Generates a random number between 0 and 3 to be used to display the
// possible answers randomly
int RandomGeneratorZeroToThree() {
    int randomInt = 0;
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    for (int idx = 1; idx <= 10; ++idx) {
        randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(4);

    }
    return randomInt;
}

// Generates a random number between 0 and 29 to be used to select the
// question to be displayed
int RandomGenerator0To29() {
    int randomInt2 = 0;
    Random randomGenerator2 = new Random();
    for (int idx2 = 1; idx2 <= 10; ++idx2) {
        randomInt2 = randomGenerator2.nextInt(30);
    }
    return randomInt2;
}

// returns true if the question has already been displayed
// returns false if the question has not been already displayed
boolean questionsAlreadyDisplayed(int randomValue0to29) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (anArray2[i] == randomValue0to29) {
            return true; // question already displayed
        }

    }
    anArray2[numberOfQuestionsDisplayedCounter] = randomValue0to29; // questionId
                                                                    // added
                                                                    // to
                                                                    // array
                                                                    // of
                                                                    // displayed
                                                                    // questions
    return false; // random number can be used as it has been used already
}

// Connects to the database to gather the question and 4 possible answers.
// Uses DataBaseHelper class
void getInfoFromDatabase(int categoryId, int questionId) {

    DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(
            this.getApplicationContext());
    myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

    try {

        myDbHelper.createDataBase();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {

        throw new Error("Unable to create database");

    }

    try {

        myDbHelper.openDataBase();
        questionFromDatabase = myDbHelper.getQuestion(categoryId,
                questionId);

        displayedQuestionFromDatabase = questionFromDatabase;
        System.out
                .println("questionFromDatabase = " + questionFromDatabase);
        answer1FromDatabase = myDbHelper.getCorrectAnswer(categoryId,
                questionId); // correct answer from database
        System.out.println("correct answer from db = "
                + answer1FromDatabase);
        answer2FromDatabase = myDbHelper.getWrongAnswer1(categoryId,
                questionId);
        answer3FromDatabase = myDbHelper.getWrongAnswer2(categoryId,
                questionId);
        answer4FromDatabase = myDbHelper.getWrongAnswer3(categoryId,
                questionId);

        myDbHelper.close();

    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        System.out.println("Errored out");
        try {
            throw sqle;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

// If the player selects the right answer this method is called to increase
// the score by 10 points
void increaseScore() {
    currentScore = currentScore + 10;
    com.triviagame.Trivia_Game.finalScore = currentScore;
}

// If the player selects the wrong answer this method is called to decrease
// the score by 10 points
void decreaseScore() {
    currentScore = currentScore - 10;
    // score can't go below 0
    if (currentScore < 0) {
        currentScore = 0;
    }
    com.triviagame.Trivia_Game.finalScore = currentScore;
}

// Displays the current scores on the activity
void displayScore() {
    TextView yourScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourscore);
    String currentScoreText;
    currentScoreText = Integer.toString(currentScore);
    yourScore.setText(currentScoreText);

}

void resetTimer() {

    if (mCountDown != null) {
        mCountDown.cancel();
    }

    final TextView myCounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    mCountDown = new CountDownTimer(21000, 1000) {

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

            questionCheck();
            resetTimer();

        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            myCounter.setText("Time left: "
                    + String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000));
        }
    }.start();

}

void cancelTimer() {
    if (mCountDown != null) {
        mCountDown.cancel();
    }

}

void questionCheck() {
    if (nextOrFinishValue == 1) {

        Intent e = new Intent(this, finalscore.class); 
        startActivity(e);
        cancelTimer();

    }
    if (nextOrFinishValue == 0) { // If 10 questions have not been displayed
                                    // yet, display the next question
        gatherInfoBeforePopulating();
        displayScore();
        populateWithQuestionInfo(displayedQuestionFromDatabase,
                displayedAnswer1FromDatabase, displayedAnswer2FromDatabase,
                displayedAnswer3FromDatabase, displayedAnswer4FromDatabase,
                nextOrFinishValue);
    }
}

// gathers question and answers from database
void gatherInfoBeforePopulating() {

    categoryId = Trivia_Game.getCategoryIdInMainMenu();

    // Loop until a valid questionId that hasn't been used is obtained
    while (validQuestionNumber == false) {
        randomValue0to29 = RandomGenerator0To29();
        System.out.println("random30 in onClick = " + randomValue0to29);

        alreadyDisplayQuestion = questionsAlreadyDisplayed(randomValue0to29);
        if (alreadyDisplayQuestion == true) {
            System.out
                    .println("question number already displayed looking for a non displayed question");
        }
        if (alreadyDisplayQuestion == false) {
            System.out.println("question not displayed yet");
            validQuestionNumber = true;
        }
    }

    validQuestionNumber = false;
    alreadyDisplayQuestion = false;
    questionId = randomValue0to29; // sets the valid random generated number
                                    // to the questionID

    // connect to database to gather the question and answers
    getInfoFromDatabase(categoryId, questionId);

    // Calls random number from 0 to 3 to determine which button will
    // display the correct answer
    randomValueZeroToThree = RandomGeneratorZeroToThree();
    System.out.println("random4 in onClick = " + randomValueZeroToThree);

    // Sets the order according to the button that is to display the correct
    // answer
    switch (randomValueZeroToThree) {
    case 0:
        displayedAnswer1FromDatabase = answer1FromDatabase; // correct
                                                            // answer
        displayedAnswer2FromDatabase = answer2FromDatabase;
        displayedAnswer3FromDatabase = answer3FromDatabase;
        displayedAnswer4FromDatabase = answer4FromDatabase;
        rightButton1 = true;
        rightButton2 = false;
        rightButton3 = false;
        rightButton4 = false;
        break;

    case 1:
        displayedAnswer2FromDatabase = answer1FromDatabase; // correct
                                                            // answer
        displayedAnswer1FromDatabase = answer2FromDatabase;
        displayedAnswer3FromDatabase = answer3FromDatabase;
        displayedAnswer4FromDatabase = answer4FromDatabase;
        rightButton1 = false;
        rightButton2 = true;
        rightButton3 = false;
        rightButton4 = false;
        break;

    case 2:
        displayedAnswer3FromDatabase = answer1FromDatabase; // correct
                                                            // answer
        displayedAnswer1FromDatabase = answer2FromDatabase;
        displayedAnswer2FromDatabase = answer3FromDatabase;
        displayedAnswer4FromDatabase = answer4FromDatabase;
        rightButton1 = false;
        rightButton2 = false;
        rightButton3 = true;
        rightButton4 = false;
        break;

    case 3:
        displayedAnswer4FromDatabase = answer1FromDatabase; // correct
                                                            // answer
        displayedAnswer1FromDatabase = answer2FromDatabase;
        displayedAnswer3FromDatabase = answer3FromDatabase;
        displayedAnswer2FromDatabase = answer4FromDatabase;
        rightButton1 = false;
        rightButton2 = false;
        rightButton3 = false;
        rightButton4 = true;
        break;

    default:
        displayedAnswer1FromDatabase = answer4FromDatabase; // no correct
                                                            // answer
        displayedAnswer2FromDatabase = answer2FromDatabase;
        displayedAnswer3FromDatabase = answer3FromDatabase;
        displayedAnswer4FromDatabase = answer1FromDatabase;
        rightButton1 = false;
        rightButton2 = false;
        rightButton3 = false;
        rightButton4 = false;

    }

    // After the 9th question is displayed, the nextOfFinishValue should be
    // set to 1 so the button displayes Finish instead of Next
    if (numberOfQuestionsDisplayedCounter < 9) {
        nextOrFinishValue = 0;

    } else {
        nextOrFinishValue = 1;
    }

}

// Listeners for the 4 buttons with answers and the Next or Finish buttons
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.answer1button:
        if (rightButton1 == true) {
            increaseScore();
            resetTimer();

            // put here to change color of button

        } else {
            decreaseScore();
            resetTimer();
            // change button to red

        }
        questionCheck();

        break;

    case R.id.answer2button:
        if (rightButton2 == true) {
            increaseScore();
            resetTimer();
        } else {
            decreaseScore();
            resetTimer();
        }
        questionCheck();

        break;

    case R.id.answer3button:
        if (rightButton3 == true) {
            increaseScore();
            resetTimer();
        } else {
            decreaseScore();
            resetTimer();
        }
        questionCheck();
        break;

    case R.id.answer4button:
        if (rightButton4 == true) {
            increaseScore();
            resetTimer();
        } else {
            decreaseScore();
            resetTimer();
        }
        questionCheck();
        break;

    }

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    music.play(this, R.raw.musicbackground); // play background music
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    music.stop(this); // stop playing background music

}
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

mCountdown is never null so change your code

```
void cancelTimer() {
if (mCountDown != null) {
    mCountDown.cancel();
}
```

}

To

```
void cancelTimer() {
mCountDown.cancel();
}
```